graph theory single bar vs double bar size notation
A follow-up on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037679/what-do-the-absolute-value-bars-mean-in-graph-theory
What is the difference between single bar $|G|$ and double bar $||G||$ notation (both seen used in this talk)? Is the former the number of vertices and the latter the number of edges perhaps?

You are correct. $|G|$ denotes the number of vertices in $G$, and $||G||$ denotes the number of edges in $G$. Formally, for a graph $G = (V, E)$, $|G| = |V|$ and $||G|| = |E|$.
For instance, consider the complete graph $K_4$:

$|K_4| = 4$ and,
$||K_4|| = 6$.

